# how to Save Data in Excel Sheet using Matlab?

Tags: excel, matlab

I want to save my data in form of table in Excel Sheet. It should look like:

```
Name |  Age |   R_no |  Gpa
Adnan |     24 |    18 |    3.55  
Ahmad |     22 |    12 |    3.44
Usman |     23 |    22 |    3.00
```

Every time when I will execute my file **classData.m** , A row will be added below. like I want to add next row as

`john |  21 |  44 |  3.53`

variable n='john', ag=22, rn=44, gp=3.53

Comment: I've updated my answer to be more detailed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Using code given by **@Tom***

It will create a new file if it doesn't already exist, and if it does exist, then it will append the row below.

```
filename='Features.xlsx';
N='Adnan'; a=22; roll=22; gpa=3.55;
fileExist = exist(filename,'file'); 
if fileExist==0
    header = {'Name', 'age ','roll' , 'gpa'};
    xlswrite(filename,header);


else

    [~,~,input] = xlsread(filename); % Read in your xls file to a cell array (input)
    new_data = {N, a,roll , gpa}; % This is a cell array of the new line you want to add
    output = cat(1,input,new_data); % Concatinate your new data to the bottom of input
    xlswrite(filename,output); % Write to the new excel file. 

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your table as a cell matrix then use xlswrite to save it to xls

That will allow you to export a table with mixed content types (numbers and text).

```
[~,~,input] = xlsread('your_file.xls') % Read in your xls file to a cell array (input)
new_data = {'john', 22, 44, 3.53} % This is a cell array of the new line you want to add
output = cat(1,input,new_data); % Concatinate your new data to the bottom of input
xlswrite('output_file_name.xls',output); % Write to the new excel file.
```

If you want to keep the same file name then you can change this slightly so its like this

```
file = 'file_to_update.xls';
[~,~,input] = xlsread(file) % Read in your xls file to a cell array (input)
new_data = {'john', 22, 44, 3.53} % This is a cell array of the new line you want to add
output = cat(1,input,new_data); % Concatinate your new data to the bottom of input
xlswrite('file',output); % Write to the new excel file.
```

Is that more helpful?

Comment: I m kind of Rookie in Matlab

Comment: First one is working Fine, But in Second "xlswrite('file',output);"  is not Correct it should be xlswrite(file,output);
and Thanks for Ur Help

Comment: is it compulsory to read the pervious records ? what if records are more than 1000, is it not time consuming?

Comment: for an xls file you have to open it and re-write. If you are able to use a *.csv format you could append a line to the file more quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xlswrite()` function as follow:

```
filename = 'Data.xlsx';
Data = {'john', 22, 44, 3.53};
xlswrite(filename,Data);
```

Fore more information you can read help for `xlswrite()` function.